# Importance of protected/private in PHP classes

Tags: php, oop

Usually when I see PHP classes, most of the variables and functions are either private or protected.  Because the PHP is executed on the server side, I don't understand why you would need these security features.  Are these available for security or am I missing something?

Comment: They are not *security* features, but elements of Object Oriented Programming and Design. [Check a few of the questions and answers given on SO about when to use which](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=private+protected+php). Also see - [PHP manual on Visibility](http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) - [Wikipedia on OOD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_oriented_design)
- [Wikipedia on OOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)
- [Wikipedia on Information Hiding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding)

Answer (score 3):

Private and protected make sense in the context of [visibility](http://es.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php), and not security features stricto senso.

> Class members declared public can be
>   accessed everywhere. Members declared
>   protected can be accessed only within
>   the class itself and by inherited and
>   parent classes. Members declared as
>   private may only be accessed by the
>   class that defines the member.

Answer (score 2):

It's not really about security, but more about the OOP design. They tell you, and other developers, how the class should be used. Private and protected variables are for *internal* use, while public members are for *public* use.