# Inheritance and except some attribute in OOP php?

Tags: php, oop

Inheritance and except some attribute in OOP php?

I HAVE CLASS A

```
class A{
    var a;
    var b;
    var c;
    var d;

    function todo1()
      {
            //more code here 
      }
     function todo2()
      {
             //more code here 
      }
     function todo_with_var_c()
      {
             //more code here 
      }

    }
```

`$A_ = new A;`

I want get a new object `$B` the same object of `A` but except `var c` `todo_with_var_c`

So I tried with inheritance in `php`

```
class B extends A{

     //TODO
}

$B_ = new $B;//$B_ will the same object  $A_ but except `var c`
and and `todo_with_var_c`
```

How Can I do it? thanks!

Comment: Why do you need this, anyway? You should be able to go around the fields and methods you don't need simply by not using them. Or am I missing something about your problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Think about the word `extends` for a second. It implies the child class is an *extension* of the parent. Think: *more than* or *special case* or "B is an A with added responsibility". This means, you can add stuff, but you should not remove anything. If B is supposed to have less properties, B should be the parent and A the extension, e.g. the other way round.

If you want to [hide properties and/or methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding) in a subclass, use [visibility](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php).

```
class A
{
    protected $a;
    protected $b;
    private $c;
    protected $d;

    public function todo1() { … }
    public function todo2() { … }
    private function todo_with_var_c() { … }
}
```

Note that I made the properties `protected`, while in your code they are `public` because `var` is old PHP4 syntax (which you should no longer use) when there was no visibility. Properties should not be public though, but accessed through accessors methods (though opinions on that vary).

Further learning resources:

- [Learning PHP class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206387/learning-php-class/2206835#2206835)
- [Importance of protected/private in PHP classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146271/importance-of-protected-private-in-php-classes)
- [Wikipedia: SOLID](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Solid_(object-oriented_design))

Comment: we should not change the class A ,because class A used in other code.is is possible if we dont want to change the behaviour of A

Comment: Actually this is better than the unset-method one.

Comment: think you should explain your answer a bit to help him understand

Comment: @IEnAk, you are not changing the behavior of the class A, you are just making some things of class A not available in class B, with scope keyword 'private' and 'protected'.

Comment: correct approach, but you should add the `$` to the instance variables, http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php, this throws an error as is, `syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_VARIABLE`

Comment: The only possible issue would be if he was already breaking encapsulation by accessing `$c` directly. Which lets face it, is more than likely.

Comment: @Gordon thanks for your answer and good resources.and thanks everybody that leaved the comments.Help  better .

Answer (score 0):

use access modifer for accessing variable or function

```
class A{
    protected $a;
    protected $b;
    private $c;
    protected $d;

    public function todo1()
      {
            //more code here 
      }
     public function todo2()
      {
             //more code here 
      }
     private function todo_with_var_c()
      {
             //more code here 
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the visibility of the variables so that only those you want are visible in the inherited class. In your example, setting the var c to private would only make it available to the class A; e.g..

```
class A {
  public $a;
  public $b;
  private $c;
  public $d;

  ...

}
```

The only possible drawback is that to access $c outside of class A you would need a getter method. You can get more info on visibility (and more detailed examples) here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php